# Как перенести все элементы управления на bitmap? C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Проблема следующая: Я считываю все контролы на форме, затем перевожу их в картинку.
Дело в том, если контрол лежит на контроле, пример: На picturebox лежат button или любые другие компоненты, то они не переносятся в картинку, то есть перенесётся тот самый picturebox на котором лежат контролы, а вот тот самый button просто пропадёт.

```
    private void pictureBox6_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        Control parent = control.Parent;

        Bitmap behind = new Bitmap(parent.Width, parent.Height);

        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            if (c != control)
                c.DrawToBitmap(behind, c.Bounds);

        float opacity = 0.8f;
        Color bgColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(255 * opacity), 0, 0, 0);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(behind);
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgColor), 0, 0, parent.Width, parent.Height);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(behind, -control.Left, -control.Top);
    }
```

Собственно мне это нужно для затемнения, но такового затемнения в WinForms нет, приходится имитировать его, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `...но такового затемнения в WinForms нет...` достаточно взять `Panel` бросить на окно, поместить туда все нужные контролы, а потом поменять в цикле у каждого контрола цвет `foreach (Control control in _panel.Controls)` `control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(255 * 0.8), 0, 0, 0);` а затем у самой панели также поменять цвет.

Comment: Опять же, не получается. Добавляю так: 
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
        panel1.Controls.Add(c);
}
Выходит полная ерунда, некоторые компоненты попросту пропадают.